# Smoothly change image source on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using css to change my image source, however it is very abrupt. How can I make the image change smoothly on mouse in and mouse out using css or jquery?

Current code:

```css
    .containerBox1:hover{
 content: url('http://example.com/prouser-newimage.png');
    }
    .containerBox2:hover{
 content: url('http://example.com/domuser-newimage.png');
    }
    .containerBox3:hover{
 content: url('http://example.com/aboutus-newimage.png');
    }
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/prouser">
    <div class="containerBox1">
    <img src="http://example.com/prouser.png"/>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://example.com/domuser/">
    <div class="containerBox2">
    <img src="http://example.com/domuser.png"/>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://example.com/aboutus">
    <div class="containerBox3">
    <img src="http://example.com/aboutus.png"/>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Thank you,
D

Comment: Well how about some basic research? https://www.google.com/search?q=change+image+with+transition+animation

Answer (score 1):

**Actually** You should not use `content` here because something like `transition` not working on `content`, instead of `content` use `background-image` and then use `transition`, you could google and find your answer faster but i answered to correct your mistake otherwise finding `transition` is so easy on google.

```css
.containerBox1 {
    transition: .3s background ease;
    background: url(https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/images/butterfly.jpg);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
}

.containerBox1:hover {
    background: url(https://media.winnipegfreepress.com/images/400*384/3229268.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/prouser">
  <div class="containerBox1">
  </div>
</a>
```